# String replacement using propertyregex

Tags: ant

Need your advice on string replacement using ant propertyregex function.

I actually need to manipulate classpath file content by replacing certain section of the folder to the new folder and and remove some folder paths.

The actual content of the class path looks like:

```
/usr/home/folder1/com/codahale/metrics/metrics-core/3.0.2/metrics-core-3.0.2.jar:/usr/home/folder1/javax/ws/rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.0-m10/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0-m10.jar:/etc/lib/:/usr/java/lib
```

which should eventually look like

```
/var/home/newfolder/metrics-core-3.0.2.jar:/var/home/newfolder/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0-m10.jar:/etc/lib/:/usr/java/lib
```

Basically, whichever string contains /usr/home/folder1, the new folder name should be prefixed to the jar file. The classpath contains 500 different groupId, artifactId with /usr/home/folder1 as the base

I am trying to replace the string in the classpath property from /usr/home/folder1/ to /var/home/newfolder/ as below. Not sure if something is wrong here, but this totally doesn't work..

```
<target name="classpath-generate">
        <propertyregex property="compileclasspath" input="${compileclasspath}" regexp="/usr/home/folder1/" replace="/var/home/newfolder/" defaultValue="${compileclasspath}"/>
</target>
```

Also, need some help on how to extract just the jar filename and prefix the new foldername.

Highly appreciate your input on this !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for extra libraries like antcontrib or regular expressions.
Use ant api via script task with builtin JavaScript engine (since JDK 1.6.0_06) like that :

```
<project>

<property name="compileclasspath" value="/usr/home/folder1/com/codahale/metrics/metrics-core/3.0.2/metrics-core-3.0.2.jar:/usr/home:/usr/home/folder1/com/codahale/metrics/metrics-core/bla.jar"/>
<property name="replacefrom" value="/usr/home/folder1/com/codahale/metrics/metrics-core"/>
<property name="replaceto" value="/var/home/newfolder"/>

 <echo>
 $${compileclasspath} initial : 
 ${compileclasspath}
 </echo>

 <script language="javascript">
  //set newProperty
  project.setProperty('foobar', project.getProperty('compileclasspath').replace(project.getProperty('replacefrom'), project.getProperty('replaceto')));

  // overwrite existing property
  project.setProperty('compileclasspath', project.getProperty('compileclasspath').replace(project.getProperty('replacefrom'), project.getProperty('replaceto')));
 </script>


 <echo>
 $${compileclasspath} changed :
 ${compileclasspath}
 new Property $${foobar} :
 ${foobar}
 </echo>

</project>
```

output :

```
[echo]  ${compileclasspath} initial : 
[echo]  /usr/home/folder1/com/codahale/metrics/metrics-core/3.0.2/metrics-core-3.0.2.jar:/usr/home:/usr/home/folder1/com/codahale/metrics/metrics-core/bla.jar
[echo]  
[echo]  ${compileclasspath} changed :
[echo]  /var/home/newfolder/3.0.2/metrics-core-3.0.2.jar:/usr/home:/var/home/newfolder/bla.jar
[echo]  new Property ${foobar} :
[echo]  /var/home/newfolder/3.0.2/metrics-core-3.0.2.jar:/usr/home:/var/home/newfolder/bla.jar
[echo]
```

To extract the jar names you might use something like :

```
<project>

<property name="compileclasspath" value="/usr/home/folder1/com/codahale/metrics/metrics-core/3.0.2/metrics-core-3.0.2.jar:/usr/home:/usr/home/folder1/com/codahale/metrics/metrics-core/bla.jar"/>

 <script language="javascript">
 <![CDATA[
 var cpitems = project.getProperty('compileclasspath').split(':');
 var jars = "";
 for (i=0; i < cpitems.length; i++) {
  if(cpitems[i].split('/')[(cpitems[i].split('/')).length -1].endsWith('.jar'))
  {
   jars += cpitems[i].split('/')[(cpitems[i].split('/')).length -1] + ','
  }
 }
 project.setProperty('cpjars', jars.substring(0, jars.length - 1));
 ]]>
 </script>

 <echo>$${cpjars} => ${cpjars}</echo>

</project>
```

output :

```
[echo] ${cpjars} => metrics-core-3.0.2.jar,bla.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is an Ant script that uses Ant's built-in file name mapping functionality:

### build.xml

```
<project name="ant-classpath-mapper" default="run">
    <property 
        name="original-classpath" 
        value="/usr/home/folder1/com/codahale/metrics/metrics-core/3.0.2/metrics-core-3.0.2.jar:/usr/home/folder1/javax/ws/rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.0-m10/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0-m10.jar:/etc/lib/:/usr/java/lib"
    />

    <target name="run">
        <pathconvert property="modified-classpath">
            <path>
                <pathelement path="${original-classpath}"/>
            </path>
            <firstmatchmapper>
                <regexpmapper 
                    from="/usr/home/folder1/.*?([^/]+\.jar)$" 
                    to="/var/home/newfolder/\1" 
                />
                <identitymapper/>
            </firstmatchmapper>
        </pathconvert>

        <echo>${modified-classpath}</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

### Output

```
run:
     [echo] /var/home/newfolder/metrics-core-3.0.2.jar:/var/home/newfolder/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0-m10.jar:/etc/lib:/usr/java/lib
```

---

The `<regexpmapper>` matches the paths that start with "/usr/home/folder1".

The `<regexpmapper>` won't match paths such as "/etc/lib/" and "/usr/java/lib". The `<firstmatchmapper>` ensures that these paths will get matched by the following `<identitymapper>`.

Comment: 1.) Doesn't work on my windowsbox with ant 1.9.3, output => run:
[echo] C:\usr\home\folder1\com\codahale\metrics\metrics-core\3.0.2\metrics-core-3.0.2.jar;C:\usr\home\folder1\javax\ws\rs\javax.ws.rs-api\2.0-m10\java
x.ws.rs-api-2.0-m10.jar;C:\etc\lib;C:\usr\java\lib
 2.) The question intended to overwrite the existing property ${compileclasspath} as the use of antcontrib propertyregex task indicates, but pathconvert won't overwrite existing property.

Comment: @Rebse, the paths in the question are all Unix-style paths. It's not surprising that running the script on Windows would get different results. Further, AntContrib's `<propertyregex>` task doesn't overwrite properties by default. The code in the question doesn't set the `override` attribute. Therefore, `${compileclasspath}` would never change. The code should be modified so it creates a new property for storing the modified classpath.

Comment: Nitpicking sure, as given property is a classpath  which _is_ OS specific, just wanted to illustrate that pathconvert
behaves different in this case, whereas my script snippet doesn't. Assumed the OP just forgot override="true" in his
snippet, as attribute property == attribute input (property="compileclasspath" input="${compileclasspath}").

Comment: Chad, thanks for your reply..I took your regexMapper approach as it pretty much did what I am looking for.. Moreover, we use cygwin in our environment to build the application, so it works as expected.